# Why does Visual Studio fail to choose the right constructor in template class?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction, template-templates

Visual Studio doesn't see the right constructor when I instantiate the template class. Where did I make a mistake?

I've already tried to make copy/move constructors explicit/deleted. Doesn't help.

```
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template <class T, template<class> class ConnectionType>
struct node
{
    T value;
    node(const T& value) : value(value) {}

    set<ConnectionType<T>> connections;
};

template <class T>
struct connection
{
    node<T, connection>* n;

    connection(node<T, connection>* n) :
        n(n) {}

    bool operator<(const connection& b) const
    {
        return n < b.n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    node<int, connection> a(0);
    connection<int> c(&a); // ERROR HERE

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error C2664:  'connection<T>::connection(connection<T> &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'node<int, connection> *' to 'node<T, connection<T>> *'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `node<int, connection<int>> a(0);` instead?

Comment: @vahancho no, `ConnectionType` is a template template parameter

Comment: This is an MSVC bug. Not reproducible with [gcc (trunk)](https://godbolt.org/z/DvD0DH) or [clang (trunk)](https://godbolt.org/z/eHzh3e). `/permissive-` doesn't help :(

Comment: this does compile well on an online compiler.

Comment: it has something to do with `connection` being a short way of writing `connection<T>` inside the definition of `connection<T>`, though I have no clue how to fix it

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 [_"injected-class-name"_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) might be the name you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a class template's scope, the name of the template actually is the "injected class name" which acts like a class member, and can be used as either the template name or as a type name, meaning the specialization in use.  ([[temp.local]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#1))

So when this name is used as a template argument, it could mean either, and so a compiler needs to check for whether the corresponding template parameter is a type or a template.  g++ and clang++ accept your code as is.  But MSVC has a bug where it often (but not always) assumes the injected class name used as a template argument is a class type, even when the only relevant template parameter is a template template parameter.  (The three compilers on the original code: https://godbolt.org/z/xrJSPB )

To work around this, you can use a qualified name like `::connection` when you mean the name of the template from inside its own scope.

```
template <class T>
struct connection
{
    node<T, ::connection>* n;

    connection(node<T, ::connection>* n) :
        n(n) {}

    bool operator<(const connection& b) const
    {
        return n < b.n;
    }
};
```

(All three compilers accept this: https://godbolt.org/z/st7liP )

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be VS's bug. VS seems treating the [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) `connection` as the type-name equivalent to `connection<T>`, but it should be treated as the template-name of the class template itself, i.e. `connection` in `node<T, connection>* n;` and `connection(node<T, connection>* n)`, because the 2nd template parameter of `node` is a template template parameter.

(emphasis mine)

> In the following cases, the injected-class-name is treated as a
>   template-name of the class template itself:
>
> - it is followed by <
> - **it is used as a template argument that corresponds to a template template parameter**
> - it is the final identifier in the elaborated class specifier of a friend class template declaration.
>
> Otherwise, it is treated as a type-name, and is equivalent to the
>   template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
>   template enclosed in <>.
>
> ```
> template <template <class, class> class> struct A;
>
> template<class T1, class T2>
> struct X {
>     X<T1, T2>* p; // OK, X is treated as a template-name
>     using a = A<X>; // OK, X is treated as a template-name
>     template<class U1, class U2>
>     friend class X; // OK, X is treated as a template-name
>     X* q; // OK, X is treated as a type-name, equivalent to X<T1, T2>
> };
> ```

PS: Your code compiles well with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5U6ZDSXXf6My5glK).

PS: It's treated as `connection<T>` in `bool operator<(const connection& b) const`.